How to create a mysql load file in python?
I want to use INSERT INTO statement in MySQL but my data is loaded like this (.csv):
id, name, age
1, John, 40
2, Mary, 23
3, Alex, 34

I'm using Python to prepare the load files and I'm struggling to get the formatting right. The trouble is I need to start rows with '(' and end them with '),' and ALSO I need strings (inserted in mysql as VARCHAR) in quotes. I tried using df.to_csv(quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC()). That only adds the quotation marks to all non-integers, but I still need to add the delimiters to separate every row. The best I could achieve is adding these (so the df is right), but when I save as csv, the delimiters themselves (not being numeric) get wrapped in quotes.
How can I best format the df to create my mysql load files?
Format required (mysql website):
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c)
    VALUES(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9);


I'm confused. Do you want to use LOAD DATA INFILE to read the file directly by MySQL, or do you want to read the file in Python and create an INSERT statement from the contents?

Or are you creating the CSV file in Python? In that case, just use the csv module, it will do all the necessary quoting automatically.

I already have the csv file itself, but I just need to add quotation marks to all non-integers and parentheses to every row. There's tons of rows so I don't want to do it manually. Is it possible to do so in python?

Use the csv module to parse the CSV file. Then use cursor.executemany() to insert all the CSV rows into the table in bulk.
import csv

with open("filename.csv") as f:
    next(f) # skip header row
    cf = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO tbl_name (id, name, age) VALUES %s', cf)

The prepared statement will handle all the necessary quoting. See How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?
